# How to get translated ModelState error message using jQuery in Asp.net Core 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to validate HTML forms in an Asp.net Core 2.0 application, using [Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#validation-attributes), [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and [jQuery Unobtrusive validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/), as strongly suggested by the docs. I also have some custom Javascript to display the error messages in a notification window.

I have a model that looks like this:

```cs
class Model
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "ValidEmail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

After many attempts, I got Asp.net to emit an `input` tag ready for validation with properly localized error messages:

```html
<input class="form-control input-validation-error" type="email" 
  data-val="true" data-val-email="L'adresse e-mail est invalide."
  data-val-required="Le champ E-mail est obligatoire." id="Email" 
  name="Email" value="test@example" aria-describedby="Email-error">
```

I have managed to get validation working client-side, *before* submitting the form. jQuery Validation correctly detects an empty field and I can display the message from `data-val-required` using Javascript. For the sake of completeness, I have something like this handling the message:

```js
function onFormValidationFailed(e, args: JQueryValidation.Validator) {
    ErrorManager.clearErrors();

    for (var error in args.errorList) {
        ErrorManager.addError(args.errorList[error].message);
    }
}

$("form")
    .on("invalid-form.validate", onFormValidationFailed);
```

However, a value such as `test@example` is accepted by the client-side validation and so the form is submitted. The error is then caught by Asp.net model validation. In my action I can see that `this.ModelState.IsValid` is indeed `false` and, as you can see above, the field was correctly identified as having an error with the class `input-validation-error`.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to obtain the pertinent error message to display it.

I tried to call `$("form").validate()` when the page is loaded to try to trigger validation, but I'm not getting any error messages. (Or at least the `invalid-form.validate` event is not being triggered.)

As a fallback solution, I tried using `<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>` to have Asp.net inject the error messages somewhere I could get them with Javascript. But this soon turned out to be a dead end because the message is not being localized!

```html
<div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul>
        <li>ValidEmail</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And indeed, I checked on the server side and the `ModelState` collection does *not* contain the localized message.

Can anyone help me find a solution where, upon coming back from the server with an invalid model state, I can get, via Javascript, the pertinent *localized* data annotation error messages so I can display them to the user? (Or suggest a better practice?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found the answer to my problem and, although it is a little embarrassing, I share it here in case other people find themselves in a similar situation.

## The actual problem

It turns out the code I was working on wasn't exactly like described above, but I didn't notice that until I tried to create a stripped-down version to reproduce.

The model looked rather something like this:

```cs
class Model : ModelData
{
}

class ModelData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "ValidEmail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The view had code like this:

```html
@model MyApp.Model

<input asp-for="Email" />
```

And the controller, had a couple of methods like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit()
{
    return View(new Model());
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(ModelData data)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        data = _service.Save(data);
    }

    var model = new Model
    {
        Email = data.Email
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

My `resx` file was called `Model.resx`.

## The root cause

what I had missed was the inheritance in the model!

Once I noticed that, everything made sense:

- When building the view, the model, of type `Model` found the translations in `Model.resx`
- When validating in the action though, the validated type is no `ModelData` and the resource manager couldn't find translations for that type since there was no `ModelData.resx`

## The fix

What I did to fix my problem is [prefer composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). My model now looks like this:

```cs
class Model
{
    public ModelData Data { get; set; }
}
```

The view like this:

```html
@model MyApp.Model

<input asp-for="Data.Email" />
```

And moved all relevant translations to `ModelData.resx`. Since `ModelData` is the type I'm building `input`s for *and* validating in the controller action, resources are always handled correctly.